# frenet frame derivation

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying to figure out why

$N'(s) = -\kappa(s)T(s) + \tau(s)B(s)$

This comes from professor Shifrin's book on pg. 11 (thank you). [http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~shifrin/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Eshifrin/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf)

We know if $ N'(s)\cdot N(s) =0 $ then $N'(s)\cdot T(s)=-T'(s) \cdot N(s)=-k(s)$

$\tau $ is defined as $\tau(s) = N'(s) \cdot B(s)$

Now some notational/ linear algebra things

$-\kappa(s)T(s) + \tau(s)B(s)$ these have no dots, so I assume we mean componentwise multiplication

Here we have  $\cdot$ in $\tau(s) = N'(s) \cdot B(s)$ so I assume we mean Euclidean product.

So perhaps

$-\kappa(s)T(s) + \tau(s)B(s)$ really means Euclidean product and we have

$-\kappa(s)T(s) + \tau(s)B(s) = -N'(s) \cdot T(s) \cdot T(s) + N'(s) \cdot B(s)\cdot B(s) = -N'(s) + N'(s) = 0$

I'm probably making some simple mistake, but I can't find it

Thank you

Comment: The dot-product is not associative. It is not true that $(u \cdot v) \cdot w = u \cdot (v \cdot w)$ for vectors $u,v,w$.

Comment: It is important to keep track of what’s a scalar, what’s a vector, and whether a product is a scalar or dot product. And do only one product at a time. When you have a term with more than one product, use parentheses generously to keep track of which product should be done first, etc.

Comment: The author assures me that he is meticulously careful with notation. Vectors are in bold, scalars not. When we multiply a scalar by a vector (e.g. $2\mathbf v$), it is precisely that. When we dot two vectors (e.g., $\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf w$), it is precisely that. The dot product of a scalar and a vector is not defined. Ben Grossmann's comment is quite misleading.

Comment: I see. I understand the notation now. Can I have a clue with one of the intermediate steps between $N'(s) \cdot T(s) = -T'(s) \cdot N(s) = -\kappa(s)$ and $N'(s) = -\kappa(s)T(s) + \tau (s)B(s)$

Comment: Review what you know when you have an orthonormal basis for $\Bbb R^3$.